# Using XPPAUT from command line

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-points

I have a somewhat specific programming question, but since the software is somewhat niche in dynamical systems, I thought I'd give it a go here, in case someone has stumbled upon the same problematic.

I'm using XPPAUT to find an unstable fixed point for a 2D ODE system, but would like to do this repeatedly in cooperation with a matlab algorithm. I know there is a matlab interface script provided, but this only seems to be able to change initial conditions, parameters etc. I'd like to automatically call XPPAUT and have it find the fixed point and write it out to me either in bash or in some file.

This is really simple, but after a lot of looking around, I'm beginning to fear that XPPAUT might only let you do these things "in hand" so and to say.

I hope I'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Just the way it stated, it seems that your problem could be solved using pure AUTO, or am I mistaken? Pure AUTO has nice AUTO-07p interface that allows you do such stuff.